# One page with two urls?

Tags: php, .htaccess

What is the best/standard way of using one page at 2 urls?

In the menu we have home, about, services we offer, contact.

On the services section, it is split in to 4 sub sections.

So the page you land on `services.php`, is also the same as `services1.php`

Is there a way with **.htaccess** or **php** to duplicate the page so if you visit `http://www.mysite.com/services.php` or `http://www.mysite.com/services1.php` you end up at the same page?

Comment: bear in mind that Google would consider this to be duplicate content, which will hurt your SEO rankings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and simple way would be to leave `services.php` as it is and just include it in `services1.php`:

```
<?php
    include("services.php");
?>
```

Or, you could use Apache's `mod_rewrite` like this (in your Apache configuration or `.htaccess`):

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    ^/services1\.php$  /services.php [PT]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about avoiding duplicating your code, why not simply include the one page in the file for the other page? So services.php would be where you maintain your code, while in services1.php you just have a one-line include:

```
<?php include('services.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use an htaccess with these lines in your root directory :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^services1\.php$ services.php [QSA,L]
```